# SQL Statement with the same multiple subqueries running very slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqlperformance

I am hoping someone here can help me. I have been given this query that takes a long time to run (over 30 min). I have been trying to rewrite the query but with no luck thus far. I am posting an example of the query so that you can get an idea of what it is I am trying to do.

Table1 has 2000 records.
Table2 has 2000000 records.

Table2 may not contain the record it is trying to lookup. Therefore a CROSS APPLY or INNER JOIN cannot be used. I think this can be solved with a LEFT JOIN, but I have not been able to figure out a way to re-write it.

```
SELECT
    ID, A, B,

    CASE WHEN c IS NULL then
        (SELECT max(distinct c) FROM TABLE2 tbl2 WHERE tbl1.Id = tbl2.Id)
    ELSE
        C
    END as C,

    CASE WHEN d IS NULL then
        (SELECT max(distinct d) FROM TABLE2 tbl2 WHERE tbl1.Id = tbl2.Id)
    ELSE
        D
    END as D,

    CASE WHEN e IS NULL then
        (SELECT max(distinct e) FROM TABLE2 tbl2 WHERE tbl1.Id = tbl2.Id)
    ELSE
        e
    END as e,
    f, g, h, i
FROM TABLE1 tbl1
```

Instead of running the 'select max' query 3 times, is there a way to join the table just once so that the "same" query is not run 3 times? The reason for the Max is that Table2 may contain several records with the same Id. In this case think of Id as an Order_Id with multiple order lines numbers.
Hope it makes sense.

Comment: `OUTER APPLY` would seem to be what you want. Although there is nothing to indicate that that is the cause of your performance issues. Really you need to examine the execution plan and determine where the time is being used.

Comment: Try an index on `table2 (id ASC, e DESC)`.

Comment: Please share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. We cannot help you properly without this

Comment: Can you please post the table definitions?

Comment: use `index` and check `execution plan` reaction

Comment: `SELECT max(distinct c)` This is just logical nonsense. MAX will return a single value - adding DISTINCT here does nothing useful. And be careful what you assume. Your subqueries can return "max" values from different rows for a given ID. Often in a situation like this the goal is to use a "first in group" approach to retrieve values from a single "detail" row (the very usefully named TABLE2 in this case).

Comment: It appears ike the OUTER APPLY is the way to go and I will also try to paste the execution plan into the link sent by Charlieface. I did add an index on table2 but a simple "SELECT * FROM table2" still takes over 3 minutes to execute. It has 2 million records. Should that really take that long? Smor you are absolutely right that max/distinct does not make sense, and I am actually changing it to TOP 1 instead as this will fullfill the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem your query should boil down to the following, does this work for you and perform better?

```
select
    t1.ID, t1.A, t1.B,
    IsNull(t1.c, t2.c) C,
    IsNull(t1.d, t2.d) D,
    IsNull(t1.e, t2.e) E,
    t1.f, t1.g, t1.h, t1.i
from TABLE1 t1
outer apply (
    select Max(c) c, Max(d) d, Max(e) e
    from TABLE2 t2
    where t2.Id = t1.Id
)t2
```

Comment: Awesome! This seem to do the trick.  And now the query takes 33 seconds. I still need to verify that the values are correct coming out, but this looks correct and soooo much faster.

Comment: Still takes 10 minutes, but that is much better than the 30 minutes before. Next, I guess I am going to start looking at the execution plan and see where the time is lost. I have added an index on table 2, but doing a simple "SELECT * FROM Table2" and getting it to display all records takes a little over 3 minutes, so the problem lies there. Table2 has about 2 million records. Should it really take 3 minutes to display in SQL Server with a non-clustered index?

Comment: There are many reasons and unknowns, you would need to post a question specifically about the performance and provide details of the tables, existing indexes and cruicially the execution plan.

Comment: Also it is 1/3 of the duration and hits your table2 once instead of 3 times, so at least that makes sense.